# How to catch 404 errors and return custom response in ASP.NET Core MVC SPA app?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application, custom-error-handling

I have a pretty standard ASP.NET Core website with Angular 7. It serves its contents from `ClientApp/dist` folder and also has some API controllers.

My Startup file has the following configuration:

```
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            });
```

My `index.html` file is in ClientApp/src and Angular build process copies it into ClientApp/dist.

I launch and serve the project through Visual Studio 2019 because I have the backend controllers, hence `UseAngularCliServer` approach alone would not work anyway.

In general, it works fine.

However, when I happen to launch a malformed API request from the Angular frontend to non-existent route of the backend, currently I get back a HTTP 500 server error:

`The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.`

**How do I configure SPA middleware or routing to return a custom response (HTTP 404 with empty JSON) instead of failing with that critical SPA error?**

Also, wondering, why does it suddenly lose the index.html file when requesting a non-existent API route, if it serves the same file totally fine when I launch the app from Visual Studio.